# Convert blank cells in Excel to numeric

Tags: microsoft-excel

I copy pasted numbers from a txt file to Excel but it recognises blank cells as non-numeric. How can I change them to numeric to do my analysis? I do not want to insert zero or anything else.
Error message:
The selection contains non-numerical data, while it is expected to contain only numerical data. (first case found in cell $J$6).

Comment: What analysis are you doing over the range that includes blank cells? You can count blank cells in a range with COUNTBLANK( ) if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to treat cell A1 as numeric if it is either numeric or empty, you can use `A1+0`. For example:

```
=ISNUMBER(A1+0)
```

returns True if A1 contains a number or is empty, but returns False if A1 contains text (even if the text is `=""`).

If you want to use cell A1 in a calculation even if it contains text, you can use `Sum(A1)` which will return 0 if A1 doesn't contain a number. For example:

```
=1+SUM(A1)
```

will return 1 if a1 contains text or is empty and will return 1 + A1 if A1 contains a number.

*In response to your comment:*

If you want the value of a cell (whether numeric or not) or zero (if the cell is empty), you can use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),0,A1)
```

Comment: I edited the answer to try to answer this. If this still doesn't answer your question, please edit the original question to clarify what your want.

Comment: ,,.how to make blank cells from non numeric to numeric as the other numeric values

Comment: @TraffyT I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: @nikolaos_mparoutis,, are you want to fill all blank cells with number other than ZERO or fill with DATE or even fill with any Cell's value??

Answer (score -1):

I solved it:
Download and Open SPSS change type to numeric and copy paste back to excel

Comment: Probably you are correct. I did that with R but my question was with  Excel. Anyway, maybe excel cannot change the storage type because it is not made for this reason.

Comment: Exactly after effort you find the limitations